# How to create PDF in ZF2

Tags: zend-framework2

I have 2 different modules in my project

1)Album

2)User

In my album module index action shows the all data of album table.

I want to create the PDF from album table data. How can I configure it and which type of class can I use for PDF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the [ZendPdf](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendPdf) package, just follow the instructions on the page. Documentation is not ready yet simply because it's not a core module. Documentation will probably follow as soon as all bugs are worked out with the core stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest DomPDF. It creates PDF documents based on html documents. It supports CSS for formatting, renders tables, embeds images and has all the features I have ever needed, and many more. It can even embed javascripts inside PDF which actually works. 
I use Zend_View to render HTML document which I then pass to DomPDF to render PDF.

http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/